# how can i have a listbox or combobox or something like that, with MULTISELECTION in visual studio

Tags: c#, forms, listbox

I have tried **checkedlistbox** , but the **multiselect** option is not supported,

Is there any thing i can add items and have **multiselection** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a selectionmode property for the lsitbox control I believe: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectionmode.aspx

Also, you could use a ListView to do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.multiselect.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this

```
listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple;
```

**MultiExtended** : Multiple items can be selected, and the user can use the SHIFT, CTRL, and arrow keys to make selections

**MultiSimple** : Multiple items can be selected.

**None** :        No items can be selected.

**One** Only one item can be selected.